# Filtering of result according the max and min

Tags: javascript

I have a function in JavaScript that compare two values of 2 turnover of 2 results of SQL queries.

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
var data = {};
[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function(clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

// Now report on that data
var output = [];
for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        var turnovers = data[client][article];
              output.push(formatName(client,article,turnovers));
        }
}

          return {
             output: output 
            };
function formatName(client,article,turnover,a) {

    return("Client: " + client + ", LRU.: " + article 
                  + ", semester t/o: " + turnovers
                  + " " + (percent = turnovers[0] === 0 ?
                               turnovers[1] : 
                              ((turnovers[1]-turnovers[0]) /turnovers[0])*100

        ));

}

output.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.percent - a.percent;
});

return("top", data.slice(0, 10));
return("bottom", data.slice(-10));    
return(data);
```

When I change my function, by affecting to the result a a variable to sort it after, my variable `turnovers` becames not recognized.

Like this:

```
function formatName(client,article,turnover,a) {

    return("Client: " + client + ", LRU.: " + article 
                  + ", semester t/o: " + turnovers
                  + " " + (a.percent = a.turnovers[0] === 0 ?
                                       a.turnovers[1] : 
                              ((a.turnovers[1]-a.turnovers[0]) /a.turnovers[0])*100

        ));

}
```

How can I resolve this problem please ?

This is an example of the result of this function:

```
"Client: 347, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 1026,-2510 -344.63937621832355"
"Client: 347, LRU.: NSS, semester t/o: 6259,0 -100"
"Client: 394, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 16951,16951 0"
"Client: 394, LRU.: FCPC, semester t/o: 3178,3315 4.310887350534927"
"Client: 394, LRU.: FCSC, semester t/o: 2536,0 -100"
"Client: 394, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 7391,0 -100"
"Client: 407, LRU.: RADOME, semester t/o: 4611,-927 -120.10409889394926"
"Client: 417, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 0,3965 3965"
"Client: 417, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 601,601 0"
"Client: 446, LRU.: MFC, semester t/o: 4232,4063 -3.993383742911153"
"Client: 450, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 892,0 -100"
"Client: 450, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 918,0 -100"
"Client: 467, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 887,0 -100"
"Client: 467, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 2500,2616 4.64"
"Client: 467, LRU.: FCPC, semester t/o: 3918,3539 -9.673302705461971"
"Client: 467, LRU.: FCSC, semester t/o: 5254,7564 43.96650171298059"
"Client: 467, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 2592,2089 -19.405864197530864"
"Client: 467, LRU.: RADOME, semester t/o: 7404,16815 127.10696920583469"
"Client: 467, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 1310,1108 -15.419847328244273"
"Client: 512, LRU.: MFC, semester t/o: 2785,2128 -23.590664272890486"
"Client: 540, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 25534,0 -100"
"Client: 554, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 750,750 0"
"Client: 554, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 954,1161 21.69811320754717"
"Client: 554, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 3848,3848 0"
"Client: 554, LRU.: FSA RCI, semester t/o: 0,10826 10826"
"Client: 554, LRU.: SEC, semester t/o: 0,901 901"
"Client: 554, LRU.: Unspecified, semester t/o: 0,428 428"
"Client: 594, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 2059,2402 16.658572122389508"
"Client: 594, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 1957,1931 -1.3285641287685233"
"Client: 594, LRU.: FCPC, semester t/o: 4281,3174 -25.858444288717592"
"Client: 594, LRU.: FCSC, semester t/o: 2870,2552 -11.0801393728223"
"Client: 594, LRU.: FSA RCI, semester t/o: 3081,4477 45.309964297306074"
"Client: 594, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 5795,6959 20.0862812769629"
"Client: 594, LRU.: IMA EYY, semester t/o: 6348,0 -100"
```

Comment: why not use SQL for filtering?

Comment: @Matus I'm need for your help, I can't understand how can I do it.Thank you.

Comment: @NinaScholz I shouldn't use SQL for filtering because the idea is to compute the AVG of turnover for each customer per article in each semester (S1 and S2), then I should compute the variation and take the first 10 customer in each sens. Thank you.

Comment: please add some data to the question.

Comment: @vero it looks like you know what you need to do: "I want take only the first 10 customers who have more increasing of turnover and the first 10 customers who have more decreasing, and register each result in variable."...  just start, write as much code as you can by yourself and then ask questions about that code. You will have better chances of getting good answers + you will learn much more.

Comment: @NinaScholz I posted some lines of the result like example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Matus thank you for your useful advance. I edited my question. I tried to use the function max but I can't arrive to a solution. Can you help me please. Thank you

Comment: @vero, please a small amout of raw data for processign and the wanted result of it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am already posted a proper data it's the result of the variation of the 2 semester. this is my result and I want how can I filtering it, to take jut the only 10 customer who has increase or decrease of turnover. Thank you.

Comment: @vero, i see a text as data, not a data structure, like an array with objects. please add what should be relevant for filtering and the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you for your answer. How can I change the result of my function to store it in an array.

Comment: you could replace `output.push(formatName(client,article,turnovers));` with `output.push({ client: client, article: article, turnovers: turnovers));` on which group do you need the max value?

Comment: When I replace by this code, the return of the function I think does not return a result (I'm very sorry because I'll test it on Monday when I'll be in my office). I want to extract the first 10 customer there turnover increase per LRU and the first 10 customer there turnover decrease also per LRU. Thank you @NinaScholz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152349/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-vero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the data by the percent value and take only the top 10 results or the bottom 10.

```js
function getPercent(array) {
    return array[0] === 0
        ? array[1]
        : (array[1] - array[0]) * 100 / array[0];
}

function formatName(client, article, turnovers) {
    return "Client: " + client +
        ", LRU.: " + article +
        ", semester t/o: " + turnovers +
        " " + getPercent(turnovers);
}

var data = [{ client: 347, article: 'ECP', turnovers: [1026, -2510] }, { client: 347, article: 'NSS', turnovers: [6259, 0] }, { client: 394, article: 'ATSU', turnovers: [16951, 16951] }, { client: 394, article: 'FCPC', turnovers: [3178, 3315] }, { client: 394, article: 'FCSC', turnovers: [2536, 0] }, { client: 394, article: 'SDAC', turnovers: [7391, 0] }, { client: 407, article: 'RADOME', turnovers: [4611, -927] }, { client: 417, article: 'FWC', turnovers: [0, 3965] }, { client: 417, article: 'SDAC', turnovers: [601, 601] }, { client: 446, article: 'MFC', turnovers: [4232, 4063] }, { client: 450, article: 'ATSU', turnovers: [892, 0] }, { client: 450, article: 'FWC', turnovers: [918, 0] }, { client: 467, article: 'ATSU', turnovers: [887, 0] }, { client: 467, article: 'ECP', turnovers: [2500, 2616] }, { client: 467, article: 'FCPC', turnovers: [3918, 3539] }, { client: 467, article: 'FCSC', turnovers: [5254, 7564] }, { client: 467, article: 'FWC', turnovers: [2592, 2089] }, { client: 467, article: 'RADOME', turnovers: [7404, 16815] }, { client: 467, article: 'SDAC', turnovers: [1310, 1108] }, { client: 512, article: 'MFC', turnovers: [2785, 2128] }, { client: 540, article: 'ATSU', turnovers: [25534, 0] }, { client: 554, article: 'ECP', turnovers: [750, 750] }, { client: 554, article: 'FWC', turnovers: [954, 1161] }, { client: 554, article: 'SDAC', turnovers: [3848, 3848] }, { client: 554, article: 'FSA RCI', turnovers: [0, 10826] }, { client: 554, article: 'SEC', turnovers: [0, 901] }, { client: 554, article: 'Unspecified', turnovers: [0, 428] }, { client: 594, article: 'ATSU', turnovers: [2059, 2402] }, { client: 594, article: 'ECP', turnovers: [1957, 1931] }, { client: 594, article: 'FCPC', turnovers: [4281, 3174] }, { client: 594, article: 'FCSC', turnovers: [2870, 2552] }, { client: 594, article: 'FSA RCI', turnovers: [3081, 4477] }, { client: 594, article: 'FWC', turnovers: [5795, 6959] }, { client: 594, article: 'IMA EYY', turnovers: [6348, 0] }];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    o.percent = getPercent(o.turnovers);
});

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.percent - a.percent;
});

console.log('top', data.slice(0, 10));
console.log('bottom', data.slice(-10));    
console.log(data.map(function (o) {
    return formatName(o.client, o.article, o.turnovers);
}));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I tried to affect a variable to my result for example  ((( var a = turnovers[1]-turnovers[0]) /turnovers[0])*100) to sort it after. Can you tell me how can affect this variable to my result. Thank you.

Comment: @vero, pardon, i do not understand the question.

Comment: Your array "data" is the array "output" in my example, I fill it by calling the function formatName. So when I replace it by output, and I delete the code of my function "formatName" it became "inknowing", because I filled the output by this function. Please @Nina Scholz How can I change my function formatName according your solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: I edited my question above, according your solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you have a `turnover` in the function parameters and use `turnovers`.

Comment: I changed it but, it does not working. another thing please, why always you delete the loop of the 2 queries ? because I should do a loop for them.

Comment: i have had times to understand you. maybe you could separate you whole project into smaller (solvable) parts and present the parts with a concrete question.

Comment: I should using "turnovers", because it's a result of the output :  output.push(formatName(client,article,turnovers));