# Sort result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 sql queries to compute each one the turnover of each semester.

Sample of the result of query 1:

```
{
  "LRU": [
    "RADOME",
    "RADOME",
    "ATSU",
    "MFC",
    "FWC",
    "Unspecified",
    "AZE",
    "ECP",
    "CMM",
    "ECP"
  ],
  "Client": [
    17346,
    17512,
    7262,
    17242,
    4001,
    17164,
    7277,
    17334,
    8059,
    300015
  ],
  "round": [
    -33250,
    -13358,
    -11731,
    -10506,
    -6005,
    -3132,
    -2448,
    -2369,
    -2236,
    -2074
  ]
}
```

Sample of the result of query 2:

```
{
  "LRU": [
    "RADOME",
    "RADOME",
    "ECP",
    "PRIM",
    "MFC",
    "FWC",
    "RCI",
    "TAV",
    "CAL",
    "ECP"
  ],
  "Client": [
    17223,
    17346,
    7262,
    7956,
    594,
    4001,
    7277,
    17260,
    347,
    8059
  ],
  "round": [
    -34276,
    -33250,
    -11731,
    -6273,
    -5684,
    -4200,
    -2723,
    -2586,
    -2510,
    -2236
  ]
}
```

I did a `javascript function` to compute the variation `(average)` between the 2 queries, then to sort them, to take only the first 10 customers that makes increase in there turnover and the first 10 customer that makes decrease in turnover.
This following my function:

```
    var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
var data = {};
[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function(clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

// Now report on that data
var output = [];

for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        var turnovers = data[client][article];
            output.push(formatName(client,article,turnovers));
        }
}

          return {
             output: output 
            };
function formatName(client,article, turnover, a) {

    return("Client: " + client + ", LRU.: " + article 
                  + ", semester t/o: " + turnovers
                  + " " + (turnovers[0] === 0 ?
                                       turnovers[1] : 
                              ((turnovers[1]-turnovers[0]) /turnovers[0])*100

        ));

}

percent.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.percent - a.percent;
});

return("top", percent.slice(0, 10));
return("bottom", percent.slice(-10));    
return(output);
```

This following her result (Sample of the result):

```
  {
  "output": [
    "Client: 347, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 0,-2510 -2510",
    "Client: 394, LRU.: ATSU, semester t/o: 0,10433 10433",
    "Client: 394, LRU.: FCPC, semester t/o: 0,3023 3023",
    "Client: 417, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 0,17683 17683",
    "Client: 417, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 0,601 601",
    "Client: 446, LRU.: MFC, semester t/o: 0,3994 3994",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 0,2595 2595",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: FCPC, semester t/o: 0,3687 3687",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: FCSC, semester t/o: 0,6731 6731",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 0,1891 1891",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: RADOME, semester t/o: 0,16815 16815",
    "Client: 467, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 0,1355 1355",
    "Client: 512, LRU.: MFC, semester t/o: 0,1523 1523",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: ECP, semester t/o: 0,750 750",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: FSA RCI, semester t/o: 0,10826 10826",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: FWC, semester t/o: 0,1161 1161",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: SDAC, semester t/o: 0,3848 3848",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: SEC, semester t/o: 0,428 428",
    "Client: 554, LRU.: Unspecified, semester t/o: 0,428 428"
   ]
}
```

Can you please correct my function to find the max and min of my customer who takes increasing/decreasing on turnover with which LRU.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me why it does not read the varaible "turnovers" please. Knowing that I used it but when I change it ( a.turnovers) it became not recognized. Thank you

Comment: Well you're not passing your function an `a` argument…

Comment: Yes exactly, how can I change it to resolve this problem please. Thank you

Comment: this is totally unsalvable, because the data is not given, on which the whole stuff is working on. it's the same with all question before from the same op. to start with, it is necessary to show the data, you have, in a stucture which is possible to work on. the question have some strings as data, which are the result of a formatting function which call is quite unclear. please start at the start, where you get the data and how the data look like. then it would be possible to sort them and get min and max values. all others is maneuvering in the dark.

Comment: what i really not understand is, you have a database query and get a structured result back. why not use this result and take it for further processing? why not use the database itself for getting top or bottom rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering of result according the max and min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757745/filtering-of-result-according-the-max-and-min)

Comment: This is the third time you have asked this same question.  Stop duplicating your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798139/how-to-sort-a-result-in-javascript-and-take-the-min-and-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal is based on the given objects and tries to get the wanted result by using an object with the needed poperties and sort it by percent.

Then for taking the top (*max*) 10 percent values, it slices the array and returns a new array which is then processed for getting the wanted strings with the information. The same applies for the bottom (*min*) percent values.

```js
function formatName(o) {
    return "Client: " + o.client + ", LRU.: " + o.article + ", semester t/o: " + o.turnovers + " " + o.percent;
}

var query1 = {
        LRU: ["RADOME", "RADOME", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "ECP", "ECP", "ECP"],
        Client: [17346, 17512, 7262, 17242, 4001, 17164, 7277, 17334, 8059, 300015],
        round: [-33250, -13358, -11731, -10506, -6005, -3132, -2448, -2369, -2236, -2074]
    },
    query2 = {
        LRU: ["RADOME", "RADOME", "Unspecified", "PRIM", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "Unspecified", "ECP", "ECP", "ECP"],
        Client: [17223, 17346, 7262, 7956, 594, 4001, 7277, 17260, 347, 8059],
        round: [-34276, -33250, -11731, -6273, -5684, -4200, -2723, -2586, -2510, -2236]
    },
    data = {},
    output = [],
    max,
    min,
    client,
    article,
    turnovers;

[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function (clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        turnovers = data[client][article];
        output.push({ client, article, turnovers, percent: turnovers[0] === 0 ? turnovers[1] : (turnovers[1] - turnovers[0]) * 100 / turnovers[0] });
    }
}

output.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.percent - a.percent;
});

max = output.slice(0, 10); // get top 10
min = output.slice(-10);   // get bottom 10

console.log(max.map(formatName));
console.log(min.map(formatName));
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry no, it worked well without "s" but it does'nt work when I add the "a". I edited my question above.Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much @Nina Scholz it worked well, just a last question if you remain me. I want my final result(min max ) there type is an array to use them in my dashboard. I changed the them in the there declaration max = [] and min = [], but it does not take it account. How can I chane them.

Comment: you could use inside of the function for keeping the given reference a pattern like `max.length = 0; max.push(...output.slice(0, 10))`. do the same for `min`, too.

Comment: Can you change your edit please above. Thank you very much.

Comment: please the last question, can you write your solution above, to change my final result in an array. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

Your function format name has **4** parameters as you can see :

```
function formatName(client, article, turnover, a)
```

And you call it with **3** :

```
output.push(formatName(client, article, turnovers));
```

And you are trying to use the fourth, that obviously can't work. Either you parameter is optional and then you test if it's set or you have to pass it to the function each time you call it.

**EDIT** :
Ok now I see some errors, I was not sure of what you were doing before.

- The data variable is defined as an object instead of an array. So you can't pus variable into it, and your are not allowed to iterate on it.
- In your first loops your aren't doing anything. Indeed you are creating variables but not pushing them into the data array. Use `data.push(key, value)`.

When you do that  : `var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};` you only create a variable `client` with the value of the variable `data[clientId]` (that I remind you is empty).

- Then you have no sorting function so you can have a sorted output. Your function called sort, is only doing a subtraction.
- And the least but not the last, your syntax, it is intriguing. You have returns out of functions.

Here are the main mistakes in that code. Try to correct that, will see then what happen.

Comment: Yes exactly, please can you give me a solution I'm already edited my question. Thank you

Comment: You have to different code in your question which one is the one I should consider to answer after your edit ? I am a bit lost...

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. You have my question answer as you like, the important is I should sort the result and to take  just the 10 max and the 10 min and of course with there ID_Client and there LRU. Thank you

Comment: I should working about the result above (I mean the average between the two semesters) I should sort this data. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah but as every one says your code is quite unclear and we need input data in order to help you. Without the input data I can't hardly figure what your code is supposed to do. I can only find some syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah this is better, but we still need a bit more ;) how are the data represented in your js script ?? Are query1 and query2 arrays, objects, string , ... ?

Comment: I'm using an sql query. it return this result above, then I use it in my function by calling it like this: var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};

Comment: I'm very sorry, I dont' have the access in my company to open a chat it's closed. But I can explain more. I have just 2 sql queries and this function above not more. I'm working by them.

Comment: But if you notice, in the function above I Converted the data of the 2 queries to a more useful data structure, keyed by client and article when I did a loop for the 2 queries. Thank you

Comment: No you do not create any data structure that we can that's the point. On each iteration of the loop you create a new variable but you do not store it anywhere so it's lost. I even wonder how it does work. The point is that we can't really help you with what you give us. Moreover I think  Nina Scholz have a good point in the comment of your question. Why don't you directly query the 10 min and 10 max on your DB ?

Comment: I don't have a DB, I'm working on Palantir cloud. I upload a csv file and I'm using an sql query and javascript. So, the two queries each one compute the turnover of a semester for each customer per LRU(Article). Then in the javascript function I compute the average between the 2 semesters (like in example that I gived you above). Next I should take the 10 max and min to display them in the same dashboard and create an alert if increasing or decreasing there turnover. So if you know it's possible to do it by SQL query, tell please how ? thank you.

Comment: you do not understand me ?

Comment: I do understand what you are saying but you did not answer my question: Are the queries string, objects or arrays ? Each case is different to treat. I cannot answer your question if do not answer mine.

Comment: ah ok it's an arrays the result of my queries.

Comment: Well, I would really like to help you but your code still make no sense to me.  `query.Client` this is the way we call an object attribute. So if I had to guess I would say that your queries are arrays of object that contains arrays. At least that what we see through your code. So can you edit your post and give the actual structure in a correct and complete description and example pls?